# Outlook not showing the events after subscribing the Ical

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

I am providing the ICal URL to my users so that they can subscribe this Ical in their Outlook.

But after the subscription, Outlook not showing the events from my web calender. It doesn't giving me any errors too. It simply displaying 'Last successful update: 6/20/2013 9:32 AM'.

How to debug this issue? Does Outlook will take some more time to subscribe the events?

**Example Ical Url:**

https://domain.com/user_token/basic.ical